# Fail to use v-bind on img src in vue3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite

Now I'm building a vue3 project in vite. But I found a weird error.

The following code work perfectly:

```html
<template>
  <img src="@/assets/images/pics/cover_info.jpeg">
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Image',
  data() {
  return {
    
  };
}
};
</script>
```

While I change to v-bind, the server failed to load the img

```html
<template>
  <img :src="ImgUrl">
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Image',
  data() {
  return {
    ImgUrl: '@/assets/images/pics/cover_info.jpeg',
  };
}
};
</script>
```

the console show following info:
`GET http://localhost:5173/assets/images/pics/cover_info.jpeg 404 (Not Found)`

Thank you for your patient and hope for your reply.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's only when using vue composition API, but vite is supposed to handle that when compiling the SFC - https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-vue/tree/main/packages/plugin-vue#asset-url-handling

Comment: Sorry, I don't know either. But this document is really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading dynamic files, because they first have to go through the bundlers - vite, webpack, e.tc. So, your implementation should be;
`<img :src="ImgUrl" />`.

```
<template>
 <img :src="ImgUrl">
</template>
<script>
 export default {
 name: 'Image',
 data(): {
  return: {
   selectedImage: "@/assets/images/pics/cover_info.jpeg", // This can be changed
  }
 },
 computed: {
  imageUrl() {
   return new URL(`{selectedImage}`, import.meta.url).href;
  }
 }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But It's seems that we can't use `require()` in vue3 project.

Comment: Updated the answer without `require()`

Comment: Do you have any idea about why vite cannot bind src dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

You need import a img in vue3 and vite

```js
//child.vue
<template>
  <img :src="src">
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Image',
  props:{
  src:{}
  }
}
};
</script>

//parent.vue
<template>
  <child :src="ImgUrl">
</template>
<script>
import ImgUrl from '@/assets/images/pics/cover_info.jpeg'
export default {
  name: 'Image',
  data() {
  return {
    ImgUrl
  };
}
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But in my project. I want use props pass the image src to the component. It's seems that I can't use import while I use props. (import must at top line). Is there any method for this situation?
Thank you very much!

Comment: So, what you're saying @Rduan is the code you posted in your question is not representative of the problem you are facing, as there is no mention of `props` in the code you posted - move the import to the component where it is appropriate then

Comment: I changed the answer

Comment: Do you have any idea about why vite cannot bind src dynamically?

Comment: Not only vite but all others (such as  webpack) ,All the vue files are compiled by plugins(or named loaders) and that's why you can use @/xxx in template or import, you can check the chrome devtools -network-js,the url is transformed to /src/xxx in dev,   and if the url  is  in a variable that cant be transformed.